# using jQuery to make a leaflet map zoom to a area of a map

Tags: jquery, leaflet

i have included a leaflet map in my site using mapbox as the map source and i just want to use a button to toggle to an area of the map, right now it shows the entire world as that is what i set the bounds to,

I should be able to create a simple event listener on a button in jQuery to move the map to lets say a country - not sure how to do that. any suggestions would be helpful.
thanks

Comment: Use the method setView().
This answer can maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527788/zoom-and-center-marker-on-click-in-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call setView on the map 
setView(  center,  zoom?,  options? )
See the docs http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview

Answer (score 0):

You can use setView method like this with latitude and longitude values:

```
_map.setView([41.062958, 28.89843], 12)
```

or like this

```
_map.setView({lat:45, lng:10}, 6)
```

check [this link](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/)